# Insert values into sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, insert

I am trying to insert some values into sqlite database in c#.all the values are label.text, but it doesn't work,i think something is going wrong:

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Data/questions.sqlite;");

SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("insert into finaltest(id,true,false,white,percent) values(3,'" + label1.Text + "','" + label2.Text + "','" + label3.Text + "','" + label4.Text + "')", con);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();         
con.Close();
```

I also tried using addwithvalue, but again it didn't work.

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Data/questions.sqlite;");

SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("insert into finaltest(id,true,false,white,percent) values(3,@b,@c,@d,@e)", con);


cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", label2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", label3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", label4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", label5.Text);         
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: I mean nothing insert into table after run. Of course even it doesn't show any error. I use "try and catch" but it doesn't catch any error!

Comment: Is that all of the code you are using? You don't have a `TransactionScope` in there as well do you?

Comment: Use debug and check if you get correctly the values you try to insert, in that way you can see if something fails

Comment: @petelids no it isn't all of my code,it is a part of codes that connect with sqlite.

Comment: i tried again and i realize that data inserted into sqlite database! because i can retrieve the last data entered to table  in my program!  but they aren't shown in sqlite tables! and in second run they disappear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click on database in Solution Explorer.

In properties window change "Copy to Output Directory" value to "Always copy" as displayed in image.

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNlkW.png)

If you think it won't works for you just close instance of database table opens in main Window then show your data again. Because when you show data if previous instance exists then it will focus on that window but didn't update.

[Check Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9fcJ.png)

It works for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try this out:
1)Select your SQLite database in Solution Explorer and change the option of 'Copy to Output Directory' to 'Do not copy'
2)Rebuild your program
3)Copy and paste your SQLite database to the bin\Debug\Data directory
4)Run your program

The update should now be committed.

Additional resources:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx

Comment: Have you tried the above steps? The database will be overwritten if it's specified as 'Copy Always'.

Comment: After you have changed to 'Do not copy', the database in bin\Debug\Data will not be overwritten so that your data will be retained in the second program execution. However, any changes in database schema in the future will require the new database to be manually replaced.